# Is HTTP content negotiation being used by browsers and servers in practice?

Tags: http, content-negotiation

I'm learning about [HTTP content negotiation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation) at the moment. I already understand the basic way client and server are able to negotiate a representation for the content requested.

I could not find out, though, what content negotiation is actually *good for*. **Are real world browsers actively using any of this?** I understand they are sending some headers such as `Accept` but their content and meaning seems vaguely defined to be.

I also wonder if real-world web applications can make use of HTTP content negotiation. **Would a realistic web application ever return different data based on these headers?** How could a server meaningfully decide based on the `q-factor`?

My goal is to understand how real web apps work in this regard so that I can better decide which parts of HTTP content negotiation I want to learn and use.

Maybe the answer is just that this is not being used in practice which would be a valid answer to me. Concrete examples for use cases would also help.

Comment: Some APIs allow for JSON or XML or some other data format based on content type requested. It is up to the server handling the request to satisify it if capable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely used a lot, for instance to negotiate formats (using "Accept", such as for image/webp), compression codings (using "Accept-Encoding", such as for brotli) or different languages (using "Accept-Language").

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work well with the browser cache implementations we're having today. They only cache one (the last used) combination of the URL and the headers mentioned in the Vary header. So if you switch between languages or encodings, the browser cache will drop the existing cached data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is surely used for multi-language pages (a web site displaying different pages for French & English users)

I would also imagine that some web interface to a version control system could use the `Accept:` header to display (when showing some C source file) either the raw C file or some HTML formatted version of it.

Comment: ... for which it would be one of the worst choices, IMHO. Different language versions should have different URLs. Redirecting the user to one of those automatically based on the Accept-Language would be okay - but serving two language versions under the exact same URL is asking for trouble.

Comment: @JulianReschke for example search engines ... even if they do send an Accept-Language header and realize that you have different language versions under the same URL, that still has the problem that what the search engine shows me in the results might not be what I am actually going to find on the page, if my browser sends a different Accept-Language header. And bookmarking, sending links to other people etc. has basically the same problem.

Comment: @CBroe - bookmarking can be a feature as well, though - depends on the use case - I do agree that having *additional* distinct URIs for different languages is good, and you can use "Content-Location" to specify them in the response.

Comment: @JulianReschke yeah, but what actual sense does server-side content negotiation make then, if we have distinct URLs for different languages in the first place? As I said, I can see an automatic redirect to one of the language versions making sense, as a “best guess” as to what language the user might want (that this actually matches what Accept-Language the browser sends would be the best case - but in reality, with people visiting internet cafes abroad, etc., it will not always be the case.)