# Why would HTTP content negotiation be preferred to explicit parameters in an API scenario?

Tags: rest, http, content-negotiation

[HTTP content negotiation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation) can be used to make client and server agree on a data format and language. Maybe you're interested in my previous question ([Is HTTP content negotiation being used by browsers and servers in practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44720631/is-http-content-negotiation-being-used-by-browsers-and-servers-in-practice)) but it's not necessary to read.

**Does this concept really make sense when developing an HTTP-based API?** (An API is a web service that is not used by end users. It's called exclusively in a programmatic way.)

An alternative to content negotiation are "regular" parameters (e.g. `http://example.org/myService?someParam=1234&lang=en&format=xml`).

Most client-side frameworks make it very easy to call a web service and send parameters. It is often much harder to configure special HTTP headers. It seems to be more work to use HTTP content negotiation.

At the same time there is no need to *negotiate*. The client will be programmed in such a way that it knows what formats and languages are available. Therefore, it will only make valid calls in this regard and get exactly what it wanted.

If the server wants to decline a call it can send an application-level error instead of an HTTP error. Application-level errors are, in my experience, easier to handle. You need that code anyway. You don't necessarily ever need to interpret HTTP errors. You can just treat all of them as a generic failure.

Content negotiation seems to fit the REST philosophy well but I'm more interested in concrete costs and benefits.

**In what way is HTTP content negotiation superior to just adding an API parameter?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't worked with many frameworks that tout the ability to work with any RESTful API out-of-the-box. Primarily, because it is just not feasible to communicate with any possible RESTful implementation without a very broad feature for configuration, which the ones that I have seen do not have. However, that is the fault of the framework, not the API.

Working with request/response headers is essential for communicating with any well-designed RESTful API. Headers are useful for sending information like access tokens and message body signatures, and receiving information like collection size and pagination details. Why not use a system that already exists for exactly the purpose of negotiating content format? Using the full extent of the existing HTTP specification is exactly what REST is about.

About HTTP errors... why would you treat them all the same? A 404 should be handled much differently than a 400 which should be handled much differently than a 409. Either I misunderstood you, or I think you are missing some of the key aspects of REST.

Comment: I do believe I understand REST but it seems pointless to me. It does not seem to matter whether I request `/customers/1234` and send `Accept: xml`, or whether I request `/getCustomers?id=1234&format=xml`. The latter seems simpler to me and accomplishes the same thing. I'm trying to find out the practical value REST, and in this particular question I'm interested in content negotiation. Frankly, it seems to me like a style that's just very fun to implement. But I'm willing to be convinced... Are you aware of some (public) API that makes good use of REST? I would take a look.

Comment: Regarding errors, I'd rather say `response.ErrorCode == Errors.CustomerNotFound` than `httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatus.NotFound`. HTTP status values only roughly map to app errors, it's the inferior system for APIs (but useful for a browser because HTTP errors map cleanly to browsing problems).

Comment: @boot4life every endpoint in REST is tied to a resource, whether that resource is a single entity, or a collection of entities. URIs are meant to define the location of a resource; the query string is not a part of that location definition. If I wanted to define the location for a specific customer resource, I would create a URI like /customers/1234. I would specify the action to be performed against that resource through the HTTP method, such as GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, or PATCH. Each of those HTTP methods can be used against the same URI to create, modify, or retrieve the resource.

Comment: @boot4life this conversation really would need larger responses than are allowed in stack overflow comments. I would suggest that you read Fielding's dissertation:
https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm
as well as the Richardson Maturity Model:
https://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html

I have written many RESTful APIs (internally) with great success, and I much prefer REST over traditional RPC convention. I would be happy to go into more detail in another forum.

Comment: @boot4life essentially, REST simply provides a specification for defining APIs. That specification utilizes the already well defined HTTP specification.  Following REST gives your clients a variety of assumptions they can make about your API before they even read the documentation. Presently, this is even leading to self-defining APIs through HATEOAS (personally, I haven't really found a need for HATEOAS though). Of course, you are free to use the RPC SOAP styled approach, but when it comes to an architectural approach like microservices, I have found REST to be the best solution.

Comment: Wanna chat? I'm very interested in hearing about your successes. Not sure how to start a chat, I don't see the "create chat" link on this page that normally is there.

Comment: @boot4life I'd be happy to regale you with my tales. REST is no silver bullet, but when applied properly I have found it to be most enjoyable. If you figure out how to create a chat, I'll join when I can. I probably won't be free until tonight though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147551/discussion-between-boot4life-and-jjones).

Comment: @boot4life I am in the chat now if you would like to discuss

Answer (score 1):

> Does this concept really make sense when developing an HTTP-based API? (An API is a web service that is not used by end users. It's called exclusively in a programmatic way.)

Yes, it still does.

> The client will be programmed in such a way that it knows what formats and languages are available.

That sounds like you are coupling the client to a specific API, which somewhat misses the point.  The client should absolutely understand those media-types that it itself understands, but why should it know what is available?

Fielding himself wrote:

> REST is intended for long-lived network-based applications that span multiple organizations.

Now, specifically with regards to *negotiation*, Fielding had an interesting observation that in most cases, you'll want [each negotiated resource to have it's own identifier.](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/rest-discuss/conversations/messages/5857)

Thus `http://example.org/myService?someParam=1234`, with appropriate headers, would return the representation of `http://example.org/myService?someParam=1234&lang=en&format=xml`.  That might be via a redirect (which seems to be the mechanism Fielding thought most suitable in 2006), or it might simply return the negotiated representation at once, with [metadata](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.4.2) providing the identifier of the returned representation

Note that the latter request is still stateless -- the server shouldn't respond any differently if you negotiate your way to the specific resource, or just as for the one you want immediately.  You might, for instance, end up negotiating with one server, and being re-directed to the representation you want on a completely different host.

That means that the servers can't really distinguish the clients that negotiate from those that don't.  You can simply wire the identifier of the negotiated resource directly into your client, and it will "work".

> In what way is HTTP content negotiation superior to just adding an API parameter?

Standardization.  With content negotiation, my *generic* client doesn't need to know anything about the spelling conventions used by your api.  The intermediary components (example: caches) don't need to know about your spelling conventions either.

> Does this concept really make sense when developing an HTTP-based API? (An API is a web service that is not used by end users. It's called exclusively in a programmatic way.)

Coming back to this point: REST is a collection of architectural constraints selected to induce particular properties.  In other words, we're making tradeoffs.  If the advantages of long lived clients aren't valuable in your circumstances, then the architectural constraints that support that use case aren't going to be pulling their full weight.

Comment: I think you're raising a very good point that REST is about *generic* clients that are supposed to work with may APIs. Is it fair to say that REST is less useful if an API is known to only have concrete clients specialized to it? Regarding caches, I believe HTTP caching is unsuitable for almost all API clients because the *client* determines how long to cache something, not the server. Only the client knows how long it's OK to show old data to the user. This is the other way around with web browsers.